# Foursquare getting and displaying venues in browser

Tags: json, jquery, foursquare

Hi i am very new to jquery and json in general and i am having trouble using jQuery.getJSON() with the foursquare API, what i am trying to do is use this search query and be able to print the results to the browser I have searched around and it is hard to find a good basic tutorial or documentation if someone could help me with getting the basic syntax of getting and printing the results to browser it would be much appreciated, here is my current code below

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&query=mcdonalds&client_id=clientid&client_secret=clientsecret&v=20120101', function(data) {
  var venues = [];
  /* print name for each venue. */
  for (var i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {
    document.write(venues[i]['name'])
    }
})
</script>
```

If you copy that url to the browser it comes back with the results in json format but i want to be able to manipulate those results and print them out selectively

here is the changes i made to get it working

```
<div id="names">
</div>
<script>
$.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&query=mcdonalds&client_id=clientid&client_secret=clientsecret&v=20120101',
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.response.venues, function(i,venues){
            content = '<p>' + venues.name + '</p>';
            $(content).appendTo("#names");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hehe i figured it out i was going about it the wrong way i have updated the changes i made

hopefully this will help someoen in a similar situation :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

hehe i figured it out i was going about it the wrong way this is what it looks like now

```
<div id="names">
</div>
<script>
$.getJSON('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=40.7,-74&query=mcdonalds&client_id=2POUFAUU4ZBJ2MTDOY3S2YHR2NIT52FYW0LUTPHBMNTJFJNQ&client_secret=YFDZI1YWV3ZI5S5SPM2DZJEQIEBPIDJ5XFZBWTIKIQZVQNYM&v=20120101',
    function(data) {
        $.each(data.response.venues, function(i,venues){
            content = '<p>' + venues.name + '</p>';
            $(content).appendTo("#names");
       });
});
</script>
```

hopefully this will help someoen in a similar situation :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be much more precise: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?intent=browse&near=51.1506269,14.968706999999995&radius=19400&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259&query=Restaurant&client_id=YOUR-ID&client_secret=YOUR-SECRET&v=20130307